# Live update international space station location in Cartopy map

Tags: python, matplotlib, maps, cartopy

I'm working on simple script to locate ISS on a world map using cartopy. Here's the code and its output

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# finding the current location   
url = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'

r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()

dt = data['timestamp']
lat = data['iss_position']['latitude']
lon = data['iss_position']['longitude']

print('Date and time : ',datetime.fromtimestamp(dt))
print('Latitude :',lat)
print('Longitude :',lon)

# plotting the location on map
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))   
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.stock_img()

# lon lat
plt.scatter(float(lon),float(lat),color='blue', marker='o')
plt.show()
```

This part is working fine and here is the output.

[image: Currently ISS is near Australia]

Now what i want is that after every 30 seconds to make a request to the url, and plot the location on the map clearing the previous location. Is it possible to do with matplotlib. I don't know much about matplotlib. Kindly help.

My current code creates new plots everytime with scatters on them. I want only one map with current location and previous location erased.

Here's my current code

```
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

url = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.stock_img()

plt.ion()

while True:
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()

    dt = data['timestamp']
    lat = data['iss_position']['latitude']
    lon = data['iss_position']['longitude']

    plt.scatter(float(lon),float(lat),color='blue', marker='o')
    plt.show()
    time.sleep(30)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) exists specifically for this kind of plot. Try this

```py
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import time
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

url = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.stock_img()

plt.ion()
s = plt.scatter([], [], color='blue', marker='o')

def animate(i):
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()

    dt = data['timestamp']
    lat = data['iss_position']['latitude']
    lon = data['iss_position']['longitude']

    s.set_offsets([float(lon), float(lat)])
    time.sleep(30)

anim = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate)
plt.show()
```

This will show (sped up for demonstration):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying sir, but this code is still not working in Google colab. It shows the map and after 30 seconds another matplotlib empty plot appears just below the map.